# Dismissing current UIActionSheet

Tags: ios4

Is there a way to dismiss the current UIActionSheet when you don't have access to the variable that holds it?

Apparently it makes its own window and makes it the key window, but [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]resignKeyWindow] doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't - you create the UIActionSheet, therefore you can keep a reference to it to dismiss it later.

Comment: Sorry, I need to do exactly this: dismiss a UIActionSheet doesn't matter which is its delegate, cause want to do it from the app delegate. 
Could you clarify how to dismiss it? how to find it? Which is the Singleton? 
thanks!